# Problem: cannot resolve constructor CSVPrinter

Tags: java, csv, intellij-idea, javafx, constructor

I'm trying to generate and load from CSV filea and problem with CSVPrinter occured. The statement is the following:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'CSVPrinter(java.io.BufferedWriter,org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat)"

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat; 
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser; 
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter; 
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.URL; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
         CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withHeader("title", "description", "priority"))

    ) {

        for (int i = 0; i < serializer.toDO.size(); i++){
            csvPrinter.printRecord(serializer.toDO.get(i).getTitle(),
                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getDescription().replace("\n"," "),
                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getPriority(),
                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getLocalDate(),
                    "toDo");
        }
```

Comment: check the documentation for CSVPrinter to see which parameters are expected by the constructor

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the details that you said you completed - there are at least two CSVPrinter classes out there (apache and Ostermiller),

Comment: import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Comment: Which version of Apache Commons CSV are you using?

Comment: org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.6

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the apache variant, your code worked for me.

I think you need to add some of the details that you assure us you have done. My guess is that you have the wrong library in your project/classpath.

- In what environment are you running your code (within the IDE or standalone from the command prompt)?
- How did you incorporate the library (download JAR directly from Apache or automatically via a service - e.g. maven)?

Here is my version of the source code:

```java
package csvwriter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.go(args);
    }

    public void go(String [] args) {
        File file = new File (args[0]);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));
         CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withHeader("title", "description", "priority"))

    ) {
            System.out.println("Done.");
//        for (int i = 0; i < serializer.toDO.size(); i++){
//            csvPrinter.printRecord(serializer.toDO.get(i).getTitle(),
//                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getDescription().replace("\n"," "),
//                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getPriority(),
//                    serializer.toDO.get(i).getLocalDate(),
//                    "toDo");
//        }
    }   catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my libraries:

[image: Project structure in Netbeans - showing libraries]

I downloaded the library from the [apache download center](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi)

When I run, I get the following as the output:

```
run:
Done.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Repeating this exercise in IntelliJ (Java Project, incorporate apache-commons-csv-1.6) via Maven, produces the same result:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59482:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\cygwin64\home\gm310509\Projects\Learning\Miscellaneous\CSVPrinter\out\production\CSVPrinter;C:\cygwin64\home\gm310509\Projects\Learning\Miscellaneous\CSVPrinter\lib\commons-csv-1.6.jar" stackoverflow.Main c:\temp\resistor.html
Done.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the "add library via maven" dialog:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check paths one more time

Comment: I may have edited my post to add a couple of questions between when you replied and now - can you have a look at my extra questions about the library and run environment?

Comment: I'm using Intellij javafx project and I incorporate the library via maven

Comment: And when you get the error, are you running it within Intell-J via the run command? Or from a command prompt using the java command?

Comment: FWIW, I've just copied the source I posted into an intelliJ project, used maven to import commons-csv-1.6 and get the same output (except it is in IntelliJ format) which I'll add to the answer.

Comment: It does seem to be a typical universal "wrong classpath" problem - SO is full of questions on this topic, unfortunately...